# Simple graph with Tikzpicture on Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

For my Master thesis I'm learning how to use Latex.

For the plots, I use **tikzpicture**  and they look very nice. Nevertheless, I'm not an expert and I need some help on how to make the following figure:

[image]

It is a very simple one and I cannot figure out how to make it. Can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not very clear from your drawing exactly what you want. If you upload a clearer picture you are much more likely to get an answer. Have a look [here](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/) for example `tikz` code, have a look at the [tikz manual](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), particularly the section 2 tutorial. If you start a `tikz` drawing and still can't draw exactly what you want upload the code as a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your very quick reply:)

Comment: The picture is one axis with some writings  aside and below a certain point with some lines (which define that we are in some special part of the line).

Comment: Anyway, I'll try to add a better picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=0.1cm, opacity=0.5, red] (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {\(T\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 4) {\(\downarrow RG\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 3) {\(t_{\perp}\propto \mathcal{O}(1)\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 2) {3DINTER};
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
            \draw[line width=0.1cm, opacity=0.5, red] (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
            \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {\(T\)};
            \node[right] at (0, 4) {\(\downarrow RG\)};
            \node[right] at (0, 3) {\(\Delta_\sigma\)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zigzag line using the `decorations.pathmorphing` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag}] (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {\(T\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 4) {\(\downarrow RG\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 3) {\(t_{\perp}\propto \mathcal{O}(1)\)};
        \node[right] at (0, 2) {3DINTER};
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
            \draw[decorate,decoration={zigzag}] (0, 0) -- (0, 3);
            \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 5) node[above] {\(T\)};
            \node[right] at (0, 4) {\(\downarrow RG\)};
            \node[right] at (0, 3) {\(\Delta_\sigma\)};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot.. it looks amazing and you've been super fast!!

Comment: Just one thing: is it possible to add something like a zig-zag line instead of the red thick line?

Comment: Awesome :) thank you very much !!

Comment: Happy to help, if this answers your question please mark it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).